# SharePoint 2013 Performance

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have SharePoint 2013 farm with 1 Database, 1 App server and 1 WFE server. We have developed a customized SharePoint portal with custom branding and some custom web part (fetching data) from List and database.

We have noticed a variation in page loading for the portal. Some times it loads within 2 second and some times it took more than 1 minute.

Distributed cache is configured on WFE server.

Any idea what causing this issue? Didnt find anything in ULS or event viewer so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to check is to create a new web application and a new site collection. If this OOTB behaves the same way, your farm has issues. If not, your custom code have issues.

If your farm has issues, start with checking

- ULS Log, with ULS viewer so you can filter out the noise in real time
- The Event Viewer, to see if there are any SharePoint related critical or error messages

If your custom code have issues, start with checking

- if your code for memory leaks using SP Dispose Checker or SPCaf or any other tool
- ULS Log, with ULS viewer so you can filter out the noise in real time (yep, always check the ULS :) )

Comment: Thanks for a quick one ! definitely will give it a try and get back to you !

Comment: Hi benny, I have noticed that sql server using maximum of the memory. After restarting the sql server process the portal performance is very fast now. But sql server process keep increasing the memory size on DB server. Any idea?

Comment: @Saad Often you need to increase RAM on SQL server as your farm gets more load. Increasing by 50% should keep you going!

Comment: currently DB server have 32GB ram. Is limiting the SQL ram usage is a solution?

Comment: You could try moving to 48 GB and see if the farm gets more work done

Comment: In worst scenario if sql consume most of 48 thn restricting the RAM usage for SQL will be a solution?

Comment: Depends on no of user, content size and feature usage. 48 GB isn't unusual with 3000 users and four five documents web apps with workflow...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55139/discussion-between-saad-and-benny-skogberg).